# Pass value to PHP page while loading it from Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on creating a widget. My jquery function is:

```
function init_widget(params){
    var protocol=window.location.protocol;
    var host=window.location.host;
    $("#wd_id").load(protocol+"//"+host+"/testfolder/index.php");
}
```

As in above code, I am loading 'index.php' using jquery. I also want to pass the value in **param** variable to `index.php`. I have tried it using ajax, by doing something like

```
function init_widget(params){
    var protocol=window.location.protocol;
    var host=window.location.host;
    $("#wd_id").load(protocol+"//"+host+"/cropimages/index.php");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:index.php,
        data: param,
        success: function() {
            alert('asdf');    
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
    });
}
```

But, it is showing error as `Uncaught ReferenceError: param is not defined`. Does anyone have any clue why this is happening. Any kind of positive suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: replace param with params

Comment: Does the error still appear after changing what messi fan suggested? If yes, at which point in the code?

Comment: Great! :) Could you revert you edit of the question again for future reference? As you've implemented the change proposed in the accepted answer into your question, the accepted answer does not make any more sense and will not be understood by future readers.

Comment: @HaukeP. Sure, changed...

Comment: Don't use `POST` for loading stuff, use `GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `params` (with -s suffix) as the argument name, but try to reference it as `param` (without -s suffix) in the function bodies. You should change the argument name to `param` as well.